# How to wait until an animation ends to test an on-click callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-dom

I've created a react component that when clicked executes an animation, and after the animation ends a callback runs. I want to test this functionality using Jest and react testing library. This is my component:

```js
export const Valuable = ({ onClick }) => {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsClicked(true);
  };
  const handleAnimationEnd = () => {
    setIsClicked(false);
    onClick();
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={isClicked ? 'animate-valuable ' : ''}
      onClick={handleClick}
      onAnimationEnd={handleAnimationEnd}
      data-testid="valuable-container"
    >
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

The test:

```js
describe('Valuable', () => {
  const valuableProps = {
    onClick: jest.fn(),
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<Valuable {...valuableProps} />);
  });

  it('should execute on click callback', () => {
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    const container = screen.getByTestId('valuable-container');
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(container);
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    fireEvent.click(container);
    fireEvent.click(container);
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).toBeCalledTimes(3);
  });
});
```

This is the error I got

```bash
  ● Valuable › should execute on click callback

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Jest, but it looks like you're expecting `onClick` to get called immediately, when it's designed to trigger after animation finishes. You may need to make the test function within `it` asynchronous, and await until animation has finished before you can expect the `onClick` to have been called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that you are running your tests in a jsdom environment. Per the [React Testing Library Setup docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup/#using-without-jest):

> However, most people using React Testing Library are using it with the Jest testing framework with the testEnvironment set to jest-environment-jsdom (which is the default configuration with Jest 26 and earlier). jsdom is a pure JavaScript implementation of the DOM and browser APIs that runs in Node.

If this is the case, [the animationend event is not supported in jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/3239).

You can work around it by explicitly [firing the animationend event](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/):

```
  it('should execute on click callback', () => {
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    const container = screen.getByTestId('valuable-container');
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(container);
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).toBeCalledTimes(0);
    fireEvent.animationEnd(container);
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    fireEvent.click(container);
    fireEvent.animationEnd(container);
    fireEvent.click(container);
    fireEvent.animationEnd(container);
    expect(valuableProps.onClick).toBeCalledTimes(3);
  });
```